# Include a variable in Postgresql query

Tags: php, postgresql

I'm getting data from an API that uses Postgresql. The following is not working. I'm getting back `{error: ["syntax error at or near "0""]}`

```
$selected_column ="some_column"; //or a `POST` (e.g.,`$_POST['my_column'];`)        
$service_url = 'https://something.html?';
       $curl = curl_init($service_url);
       $curl_post_data = array(
            "q" => "SELECT something, another, thing, rank() OVER ( ORDER BY " + $selected_column + " DESC)  from my_database",
            "api_key" => 'XXXYYYZZZ',
            );
       curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
       curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
       curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $curl_post_data);
       $curl_response = curl_exec($curl);
     echo $curl_response;
```

However, if I put the column value from `$selected_column` "hard coded" into the query, it works fine. That is, just changing this line:

```
 "q" => "SELECT something, another, thing, rank() OVER ( ORDER BY some_column DESC)  from my_database",
```

I'm guessing I can't pass a variable like this, but I'm at a loss for how you can do it.

Thanks.

Comment: You use a . not a + to concatenate strings in php

Comment: @BarbaraLaird Ugh...been writing so much javascript and jQuery, I got in a bad habit. Thanks! That was the problem.

Comment: Be super extra mega sure you're not using `$_POST` data in your query without testing it carefully. In the case of column names you should have a white-list of acceptable values and reject anything else.

Comment: @tadman Thanks for the reminder. I do have a whitelist of acceptable `$_POST` data, but I left it out of my example code for simplicity.

Comment: @jonmrich I can't tell you how many times I've made the same mistake :)